# SQL Server : select top 10 sum from each year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a list of items for which I'd like to pull out the top 10 items by year. What would be the best way to do this? I'm running on SQL Server 2012.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast)  AS 'Year',
    MONTH(b.DateOfServiceLast) AS 'Month',
    b.DiagnosisCode,
    SUM(c.Paid) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast), MONTH(b.DateOfServiceLast), (b.DiagnosisCode)) AS 'Cost',
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast), MONTH(b.DateOfServiceLast) ORDER BY YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast), MONTH(b.DateOfServiceLast)) AS 'Row'
FROM
    MO_CMTExtract.dbo.ProfessionalClaim a
LEFT JOIN
    MO_CMTExtract.dbo.ProfessionalClaimDetail b ON a.ProfessionalClaimID = b.ProfessionalClaimID
LEFT JOIN
    MO_CMTExtract.dbo.ProfessionalClaimDetailMoney c ON b.ProfessionalClaimDetailID = c.ProfessionalClaimDetailID
ORDER BY
    YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast),
    MONTH(b.DateOfServiceLast),
    b.DiagnosisCode,
    Row, Cost;
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @marc_s your comment just got Jackson 5's abc easy as 123 song stuck in my head! :D

Answer (score 1):

Using `WITH TIES` is one method. I kept your query as you had it, but wrapped it in a `CTE` and removed the ORDER BY. Then, we use `WITH TIES` against that `CTE`.

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
        YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast)  AS 'Year',
        MONTH(b.DateOfServiceLast) AS 'Month',
        b.DiagnosisCode,
        SUM(c.Paid) OVER (PARTITION BY
                              YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast),
                              MONTH(b.DateOfServiceLast),
                              (b.DiagnosisCode)
                         )         AS 'Cost',
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
                               YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast),
                               MONTH(b.DateOfServiceLast)
                           ORDER BY
                               YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast),
                               MONTH(b.DateOfServiceLast)
                          )        AS 'Row'
FROM
        MO_CMTExtract.dbo.ProfessionalClaim            a
    LEFT JOIN
        MO_CMTExtract.dbo.ProfessionalClaimDetail      b
            ON a.ProfessionalClaimID = b.ProfessionalClaimID
    LEFT JOIN
        MO_CMTExtract.dbo.ProfessionalClaimDetailMoney c
            ON b.ProfessionalClaimDetailID = c.ProfessionalClaimDetailID)

SELECT TOP 10 WITH TIES *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY COST DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` as follows and then filter using row numbers:

```
WITH cte_base
AS (   SELECT  DISTINCT
               YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast)  AS 'Year',
               MONTH(b.DateOfServiceLast) AS 'Month',
               b.DiagnosisCode,
               SUM(c.Paid) OVER (PARTITION BY
                                     YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast),
                                     MONTH(b.DateOfServiceLast),
                                     (b.DiagnosisCode)
                                )         AS 'Cost'
       FROM
               MO_CMTExtract.dbo.ProfessionalClaim            a
           LEFT JOIN
               MO_CMTExtract.dbo.ProfessionalClaimDetail      b
                   ON a.ProfessionalClaimID = b.ProfessionalClaimID
           LEFT JOIN
               MO_CMTExtract.dbo.ProfessionalClaimDetailMoney c
                   ON b.ProfessionalClaimDetailID = c.ProfessionalClaimDetailID),
     cte_rownum
AS (   SELECT
           cte_base.Year,
           cte_base.Month,
           cte_base.Cost,
           cte_base.Row,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
                                  YEAR(b.DateOfServiceLast)
                              ORDER BY
                                  cte_base.Cost DESC
                             ) AS 'Rownum'
       FROM
           cte_base)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte_rownum
WHERE
    cte_rownum.Rownum <= 10
ORDER BY
    cte_rownum.Year,
    cte_rownum.Month,
    cte_rownum.Cost DESC;
```